# perl regex matching expression

Tags: regex, perl

I'm parsing space-delimited lines from a file with the instruction:

```
($F1,$F2) = split(/\s/,$_);
```

And in a line like

```
TEXT1 TEXT2 TEXT3
```

I need `$F2` to be `TEXT2 TEXT3` not only `TEXT2`. How can I do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`split` may be passed a third argument: LIMIT (i.e. number of fields to split into).](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)

```
($F1,$F2) = split(/\s/,$_,2);
```